# User ID or Username

Tags: database, cakephp

I have a CakePHP app that uses the default "Created By" behaviour to store user IDs of authors of articles (for example - amongst other things).

Is it better to store the User ID or the Username in the Created By field?

My instinct is the User ID, but what if somehow something got out of sync and the authors got mixed up during database version migrations etc.

Probably a stupid question, but what do you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store user ID, not user name. Highly likely in your SQL schema, you'll have this as a foreign key, ie being a primary autoincrement key in another table.

This is more efficient in terms of indexing and takes less space than the name.

Comment: This is nearly always the best way, if you are debating between using the id or another field in a table as a foreign key in another table then you should definitely go for the id

Comment: I always have done, I just had a brain fart and thought "well what if the IDs slipped out of sync" ... but they shouldn't be doing. Nevermind :D